# Win32 application not appearing in Start Menu search

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry, nsis

I have built a Win32 application and that application is installed via a custom NSIS install script. The application installs and executes with no issue. However, when I go to search for the App or find the app in the programs list(in both Windows 10 and Windows 7), it is not listed. I am assuming I need a registry value added but am not certain. I've already added registry values at `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[my app name]` in order to see the app in Programs and Feature for uninstall.

I tried adding this registry key also but it doesn't appear to do anything
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\[my app executable]`

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Create a shortcut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127425(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\MyApp.lnk" "$INSTDIR\MyApp.exe"
```

The App Paths key is used when the user types just a filename in the Run dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

Comment: Worked like a charm! The syntax should be `CreateShortCut` however I think. I didn't try it as `CreateShortcut` but NSIS documentation has a capital C

Comment: NSIS instructions are not case-sensitive. I thought I fixed that uppercase C typo in NSIS 3 already but I guess not.